# How do I access mysql over the network?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a development box and a development server.

I have some development tools on my development box with which I want to access MySQL residing on a development server.

The development server was set up with XAMPP.

How do I make mysql available over the network?  What do I use for the host name?

Thanks

Comment: My friends-that-knows-much says: http://rclermont.blogspot.com/2008/05/configuring-mysql-for-network-access.html Use the appropriate hostname (one that resolves to the server machine).

Answer (score 9):

comment out the line:

```
skip-networking -> #skip-networking
```

in the file:

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security` set the mysql root password

Step 2: Access the database as `sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p` then enter password of root user.

Step 3: Run the query run this query.
`GRANT ALL ON <db_name>.* TO <user_name>@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<some_password>';` and then type `exit`.

Step 4: Edit my.cnf (should be at /opt/lampp/etc/) and comment the line:

skip-networking

This line is uncommented when you run the Lampp security tool.

As

`sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf`, after comment as `#skip-networking` type `control+x` => `y` => `enter`

NOTE: Of course, you should take the necessary steps to secure your databases properly after enabling network access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 0):

**For accessing mysql of XAMPP over a network :**

-go to xammp directory
XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\

-open httpd-xampp.conf file and comment the Require local

```html
#
# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        #Require local        
       
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

-create the database in mysql and create new user with username and password
with Host : % (any host) which will allow to connect the 'username'@'%' over the network

-open command prompt type ipconfig

now you can access the mysql at your ipaddress:3306
(3306 is default port for mysql)